# Wordpress: How to edit mail regarding email address change?

Tags: wordpress

I would like to change the content of the mail, that is sent to the old mailaddress when a user changes his/her mailaddress.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Stackoverflow is a place for people to find help with their code issues. What you're asking for is an indepth tutorial and this is not the place for that. Have you at least attempted to Google how to do this?

Comment: To answer your question specifically of "Is there a way to do this?" - The answer is "yes".

Comment: @GBWDev yes i did, but all i could find was answers to questions on how to change sender address of wordpress.I'm not looking for a indepth tutorial I just needed a little hint. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this free plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/manage-notification-emails/

**OR**

By using the WordPress filter hook `email_change_email` you can modify email content. You can found more info about this hook at https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/email_change_email/